# Why is Scala 'match' stuck in a forever loop

Tags: scala, loops, testing, recursion

I'm trying to find out if numbers are descending within a list in Scala. When I run my test cases, the console prints an arbitrary list and never completes, making me think it's stuck in a forever loop.

The function isDescending must take a list as a parameter, and must return a boolean. We must use recursion and cannot use functions from the collections package.

Code:

```
  def isDescending(lst: List[Int]): Boolean ={
    isDescendingHelper(lst, 0, true)
  }

  def isDescendingHelper(lst: List[Int], prev: Int, begin: Boolean): Boolean = {
    lst match{
      case Nil =>  true
      case head :: tail => {
        if (begin){
          isDescendingHelper(lst, head, false)
        } else if (head <= prev){
          isDescendingHelper(lst, head, false)
        } else {
          false
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Test Cases:

```
  test("isDescending test case"){
    assert(isDescending(List()))
    assert(isDescending(List(0, 0, 0)))
    assert(isDescending(List(3, 6, 8)))
    assert(isDescending(List(3, 6, 8 , 7)) == false)
    assert(isDescending(List(0)))
  }
```

Comment: You should pass `tail` to the function, instead of `lst` withing isDescendingHelper

Comment: As a side note, consider if you could make this function more concise using `zip`  and another higher-order function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always match on the same list `lst`, doing so the list will never be exhausted, you want to pass in the tail:

```
def isDescendingHelper(lst: List[Int], prev: Int, begin: Boolean): Boolean = {
  lst match{
    case Nil =>  true
    case head :: tail => {
      if (begin){
       isDescendingHelper(tail, head, false)
      } else if (head <= prev){
        isDescendingHelper(tail, head, false)
      } else {
        false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Also the `if (begin)` and `else if (head <= prev)` do exactly the same thing. Thus, the first `if else` can be removed as well as the `begin` parameter.